# TeXnic Center Running a file while the PDF is Open

Tags: texniccenter

I am having trouble with running the `.tex` file, while the `PDF` output is open. It does not allow me to run the file while it is open, thus I need to close it in order to run the `.tex` file. Is there any way to overcome this?

p.s: I am doing it in Dropbox. Can this be the reason?

Comment: see [configure-texniccenter-with-something-else-than-adobe-reader-x](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12500/configure-texniccenter-with-something-else-than-adobe-reader-x) and try Sumatra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you need to configure the viewer setting in TeXnicCenter as follows.

[image]

### Edit 3

I am assuming that you use Adobe Acrobat Reader 32 bit version 10.x.

Comment: Alternatively, [you could use SumatraPDF for your viewer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15398/3345). It doesn't lock the PDF file the way Adobe Reader does.