# Unable to generate pdf

Tags: errors, compiling, windows, texmaker, texniccenter

I use TeXnicCenter and get the following error window after I try to compile

[image]

Even TexMaker is unable to create the pdf file.

No error is detected in the window below after compilation.

Comment: How about command-line generation of the pdf ?

Comment: as @ach said [Verify a latex installation: Commandline/Terminal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101890/15717). if there is no latex installation, you need a latex distribution (MiKTeX or TeXLive) to get a `.pdf` from `.tex`.

Comment: Strangely, with TeXworks I am able to generate pdf. Btw thanks ach, texenthusiast. Cheers.

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora This is a very common problem.  Have you tried re-opening TeXnicCenter?  Are you sure you haven't selected anything on the pdf? (to be sure, please close before running your file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be a lot of issues for this error to be generated.  The most common ones are:

1. Since TeXnicCenter is in version beta 2.0, it still has bugs.

   ⇒ Try closing the program and re-opening it.
2. You have selected something on the pdf file and now TeXnicCenter is unable to write in the file

   ⇒ Try closing the pdf and then re-run the LaTeX file.
3. Your .aux files are corrupted.

   ⇒ You can delete them and re-run your original ones.
4. Your pdf file is corrupted.

   ⇒ Once again, delete it and run your LaTeX file normally
5. There is a problem with your reader (in case you are not using the latest version of TeXnicCenter)

   ⇒ See these posts:

   - [MiKTeX / TeXnicCenter / Adobe Reader: No pdf produced](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73020/miktex-texniccenter-adobe-reader-no-pdf-produced) and
   - http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=10857&start=0

---

Related posts:

- [Problem in TeXnicCenter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15392/problem-in-texniccenter/15448#15448)
- [Configure TexnicCenter with something else than Adobe Reader X](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12500/configure-texniccenter-with-something-else-than-adobe-reader-x/44672#44672)
- [TeXnicCenter & Adobe Acrobat 10](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43864/texniccenter-adobe-acrobat-10)

Comment: Have a look at my edit to see how to use markdown list formatting.